# Given a high number of elements |M| with a constant length of |m|, which algorithm can index |M| with a length <|m|?

Tags: math, indexing, compression, codec, hash

This question is language independent, so I adress all of you intelligent programers to help me somehow.

Given is a set of elements "M" with |M| = 2^128 elements. Every element "m" has a bit-length of 128 bits.

I want to send a message with the length of 128 Bit. In this message, I want to incorporate one of the elements of M and some information "n". That means, "m" and "n" have to be in length < 128 bit (length of the message).

The other party has the complete set "M" with all elements, but I need to tell him/her which element she/he has to use. This instruction has to fit in one meassage and can't be splitt up several messages.

So, I want to index my elements with an algotithm f(), so that f(m)=index_of_m with index_of_m<128 bit.

In other words, the algorithm has to map 2^128 elements of a length of 128 bit on an index that is represented with less bits than the length of the elements (128 bit).

Formal again:

The set:

```
M=(m1,m2,...mn) with n = 2^128
```

Length of every `m1...mn: 128 bits.`

A message `"n" < 128 bit`. Message length is variable and could be 1 bit.

Indexing/mapping function: f()

```
f(m1)=i1  Index 1 of element m1 with the length of i1 < 128 bit., so i1+n=128bit
Wanted: Function f().
```

Ideas:

-Hashes won't work in a simplistic way of hashing the elements, as a hash with a 64bit output can' encode the 2^128 elements. A hash with a 128 bit output will use up the whole message, and there will be no place for "n".

-Indexing from 1 to 2^128 won't work, as e.g., 2^128 will use up the whole message.

Comment: If you want a unique 1:1 mapping to 2^128 elements, I can't see why an index of 2^128 wouldn't be the minimum. Is there some theory behind this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

No.

If by "a set" you mean a set, i.e. no repeated elements and order does not matter, then your M is simply the set of all integers in the range 0..2<sup>128</sup>-1.

There is no representation of all of the elements of M that is less than 128 bits for all elements.  If there were, then there simply by counting, there are not enough representations to map to all of the elements, which is a contradiction.